# TypeNotFoundException: Type ChangeAssetValue is not defined in namespace org.acme.biznet

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) tutorial. At step three, the command

> composer archive create -t dir -n .

returns the following error:

```
TypeNotFoundException: Type ChangeAssetValue is not defined in namespace org.acme.biznet
Command failed
```

Comment: This occurs because somewhere in your Model you are referring to a type `ChangeAssetValue`  but you have not defined it in your model. See the modeling language for examples -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/cto_language.html

Comment: A similar problem I found, I recheck the network name and path and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

"ChangeAssetValue" type is defined in the file *logic.js*, so I guess instead of modifying the file "*tutorial-network/lib/logic.js*", you have changed the one that is in "*/tutorial-network/test/logic.js*", I had the same problem and I corrected it like that: modify the correct file :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately create your whole business network on the [online composer-playground](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net) and then export the `.bna` file and directly deploy it on your local composer.

This would be more convenient and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Run **grep -nr 'ChangeAssetValue' .** in your project directory to find where you have used ChangeAssetValue. Either declare it in your .cto file or change ChangeAssetValue to what you have declared in your .cto file.